# XSLT recursive calling

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML with parent-child relationship

```
<EntityList>
    <item>
        <itemType>Parent</itemType>
        <itemInfo>
            <itemId>Parent1</itemId>
        </itemInfo>
        <childList>
            <item>
                <itemType>Case</itemType>
                <itemInfo>
                    <itemId>Case1</itemId>
                </itemInfo>
                <childList>
                    <itemGroup>
                        <itemType>Product</itemType>
                        <groupItem>
                            <groupItemInfo>
                                <itemId>Product1.0</itemId>
                            </groupItemInfo>
                            <groupItemInfo>
                                <itemId>Product1.1</itemId>
                            </groupItemInfo>
                        </groupItem>
                    </itemGroup>
                </childList>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemType>Case</itemType>
                <itemInfo>
                    <itemId>Case2</itemId>
                </itemInfo>
                <childList>
                    <itemGroup>
                        <itemType>Product</itemType>
                        <groupItem>
                            <groupItemInfo>
                                <itemId>Product2.0</itemId>
                            </groupItemInfo>
                            <groupItemInfo>
                                <itemId>Product2.1</itemId>
                            </groupItemInfo>
                        </groupItem>
                    </itemGroup>
                </childList>
            </item> 
            <item>
                <itemType>Case</itemType>
                <itemInfo>
                    <itemId>Case3</itemId>
                </itemInfo>
                <childList>
                    <itemGroup>
                        <itemType>Product</itemType>
                        <groupItem>
                            <groupItemInfo>
                                <itemId>Product3.0</itemId>
                            </groupItemInfo>
                            <groupItemInfo>
                                <itemId>Product3.1</itemId>
                            </groupItemInfo>
                        </groupItem>
                        <!-- -->
                    </itemGroup>
                </childList>
            </item> 
        </childList>
    </item>
</EntityList>
```

and i need to get output like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Body>
    <EntityList>
        <Event>
            <parentID>Parent1</parentID>
            <child>
                <name>Case1</name>
                                    <name>Case2</name>
                                    <name>Case3</name>
            </child>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <parentID>Case1</parentID>
            <child>
                <name>product1.0</name>
                <name>product1.1</name>
            </child>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <parentID>Case2</parentID>
            <child>
                <name>product2.0</name>
                <name>product2.1</name>
            </child>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <parentID>Case3</parentID>
            <child>
                <name>product3.0</name>
                <name>product3.1</name>
            </child>
        </Event>
    </EntityList>
</Body>
```

by using this xslt i'm able to get the parentID and getting the child for corresponding parentID is little bit tricky for me.It means that it has to call recursively

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gs1ushc="http://epcis.gs1us.org/hc/ns" >
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <Body>
        <EntityList>
        <xsl:for-each select="//itemAggr">
            <Event>
                <xsl:if test="//childList">
                <parentID><xsl:value-of select=".//itemId" /></parentID>
                <child>
                    ????
                </child>
            </xsl:if>
            </Event>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </EntityList>
    </Body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XML is not valid. Please put correct XML file

Comment: In the original XML it looks like that "Case1", "Case2" and "Case3" are all in the child list for Parent1. However, in the expected output it looks like only "Case1" is the child. What links a child "Case" to a parent?

Comment: Thanks @Tim C i've updated the o/p xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
xmlns:gs1ushc="http://epcis.gs1us.org/hc/ns" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <Body>
            <EntityList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="EntityList/item"  mode="parent"/>
            </EntityList>
        </Body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match ="item" mode="parent">
        <Event>
            <xsl:if test="childList">
                <parentID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="itemInfo/itemId" />
                </parentID>
                <child>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="childList"  />
                </child>
            </xsl:if>
        </Event>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="childList/item" mode="parent"/>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="itemType" />

    <xsl:template match ="item">
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="itemInfo/itemId" />
        </name>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match ="groupItemInfo">
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="itemId" />
        </name>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which generates the following output:

```
<Body xmlns:gs1ushc="http://epcis.gs1us.org/hc/ns">
  <EntityList>
    <Event>
      <parentID>Parent1</parentID>
      <child>
        <name>Case1</name>
        <name>Case2</name>
        <name>Case3</name>
      </child>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <parentID>Case1</parentID>
      <child>
        <name>Product1.0</name>
        <name>Product1.1</name>
      </child>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <parentID>Case2</parentID>
      <child>
        <name>Product2.0</name>
        <name>Product2.1</name>
      </child>
    </Event>
    <Event>
      <parentID>Case3</parentID>
      <child>
        <name>Product3.0</name>
        <name>Product3.1</name>
      </child>
    </Event>
  </EntityList>
</Body>
```